# expiry date using utc timestamp, mysql and php?

Tags: php, mysql, utc

How do you add time or days to a current `utc_timestamp`?

I am using;

```
new CDbExpression('UTC_TIMESTAMP()')
```

for both 'created' and 'updated' fields in my mysql table but would like to add an 'expiry' field which would allow 4 days from creation date. I presume this is possible but am unsure how.

Answer (score 0):

for insert/update current time

UPDATE table
SET created = NOW()

for 4 days from creation date
SELECT * FROM table WHERE created > DATE_SUB( NOW( ), INTERVAL 4 DAY )

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL :

```
ALTER TABLE `table` 
    ADD expiry datetime DEFAULT DATE_ADD( utc_timestamp( ) , INTERVAL 4 DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

> "The DEFAULT value  clause in a data type specification indicates a
> default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must
> be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression. This means,
> for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be
> the value of a function such as NOW()  or CURRENT_DATE."

So, this is explicitely documented limitation

you have to create `TRIGGER` if your MySQL Version < 5.6.5

**BUT**

[`MySQL 5.6.5 changelog stats`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

> As of **MySQL 5.6.5**, TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns can be automatically
> initializated and updated to the current date and time (that is, the
> current timestamp). Before 5.6.5, this is true only for TIMESTAMP, and
> for at most one TIMESTAMP column per table.

Reference :

#### http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=27645

#### http://optimize-this.blogspot.in/